# hash file Model (Machine learning algorithm)

Tags: solidity, blockchain, remix, machine-learning

I want to implement a model file (SVM for example) in a smart contract to do hash.

is this idea correct? How and where can I start? can i use IDE remix solidity to implement all this. Thank you.

Comment: Would love to help, but could you explain what you wish to do in more detail? And also, I am interested in what benefit do you hope to get from implementing such a thing on the blockchain.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I am working on a project "securing machine learning algorithms against poisoning attacks
for that I use the smart contract to introduce the model in the blockchain and hash the model files (SVM for example) in order to protect the privacy of IoT systems (Internet of things)
my problem how to do it with solidity?

Comment: Alright, yeah you can hash any data you write into a smartContracts. That is a given. I am not sure how to help in your specific case as I have no expertise in machine learning. But if we are talking about the application of hash functions in smart contracts, this link might help. https://solidity-by-example.org/hashing/  It's one of the best learning tools for understanding solidity and smartContracts.